# How to evaluate integral solutions of a permutation inequality

Tags: combinatorics

**Find the number of integral solutions of** $$x_1+x_2+x_3<36$$ such that $x_i$ (for i= $\{1,2,3\}$) varies as $$1\le x_i\le23$$

> My initial attempt in this problem was to introduce a 'dummy' variable to remove the inequality such that $x_1+x_2+x_3+y_4=35$.   $y_4$ being the dummy variable. Now since $x_1,x_2,x_3$ has restrictions I tried to replace $x_i\rightarrow y_i+1$ transforming my equation into $$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=32$$ with the restriction now that $0\le y_i \le 22$ And again there is no such restriction on $y_4$ and the number of solutions of such equations is generally, Coefficient of $x^{32}$ in $$(x^0+x^1+x^2....x^{22})^3(x^0+x^1+x^2....x^{33})^1 $$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{(x^{23}-1)^3}{(x-1)^3}.\frac{(x^{33}-1)}{(x-1)}$$
$$\Rightarrow (x^{23}-1)^3(x^{33}-1)(x-1)^{-4}$$
which leaves us to find the coefficient of $x^{32}$ and $x^{9}$ we shall invoke the formula $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$ But my answer was off by a mile.

Where did I go wrong with this method? is this method wrong for such problems, if so, why?

Comment: be careful when you add dummy variable, the result is not $36$ , it is $35$ because $x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 35 \rightarrow x_1+x_2+x_3 +y_4= 35 $

Comment: you are indeed correct but even after this modification, the answer wont match ( i am supposed to get 855 apparently), or is this answer wrong?

Comment: after that you should find the coefficient of $[x^{32}]$ , did you do this ?, or did you still calculated for $[x^{33}?]$

Comment: Also $(x^{23}-1)^3$ in numerator of first term ?

Comment: @Bulbasaur Yes I have edited the post just now to make the following changes, again while using $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$ the value of $n=4$ , the $x^{33}-1$ term will contribute nothing but a negative sign, so i will once use this formula to set $r=32$ which multiplies with $-1$, and $r=9$ to get coeff of $x^{32}$ after this term is multiplied with power of $23$ in the first power to ultimately get $\binom{35}{2}-\binom{12}{9}$ which is  $6325$

Comment: @trueblueanil yes, i have tried doing that

Comment: @PoisonedVenom https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+of+%281-x%5E23%29%5E3%281-x%29%5E%28-4%29%281-x%5E33%29

Comment: I dont understand where I  chose the wrong powers? (also none of the terms in this expansion turns out to be $855$ (given answer) why is it so?)

Comment: @trueblueanil Why do you say so? infact after pondering upon your comment, I realized $y_4$ should actually vary between $-34 \to 32$ (when all of $x_i$'s assume extreme values ) which would change the powers of $y_4$ but that again gave me an absurd result for some reason

Comment: That is happening because $y_4$ was not defined as a non-negative integer.

Answer (score 1):

In your answer of $6225$, for $\binom{35}2$, I think you meant $\binom{35}3$

I am getting a somewhat different answer though, starting from

$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=32, 0\leq y_i\leq22$

Using the normal stars and bars formula, and applying PIE we get

$\binom{32+4-1}{4-1} - \binom31\binom{9+4-1}{4-1}$

$=\binom{35}3 - \binom31\binom{12}3 = 5885$